# Read more button which removes max-height gradually

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've a "Read More" button which increases the height of a `div` by removing the css attribute `max-height` but I would like an animation like with the jQuery `slideToggle()` function to "pull down" the rest of the div.

This is my code :

```
<div id="Presentation" style="text-align:justify;"><?php echo $data['texte_presentation'];?></div>
            <div id="fadeout" class="fadeout" style="display:none;"></div>
                <div id="DivReadMore" style="text-align:right;margin-top:-4em;display:none;">
                <hr style="margin:5px;"><button id="BoutonReadMore" class="btn btn-warning btn-block"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Lire la suite</button>
                </div>
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                ReadMore();
                $(window).on('resize', function(){
                    if($('#Presentation').hasClass("read-more"))
                    {}else{
                      ReadMore();
                    }
                });
                $("#BoutonReadMore").click(function(){
                  $("#Presentation").css({'max-height':'', 'overflow':''});
                  $("#DivReadMore").hide();
                  $("#fadeout").hide();
                  $("#Presentation").addClass("read-more");
                });
            });
            function ReadMore() {
                var hauteur = $('#Presentation').height();
                if(hauteur > 200)
                {
                    $("#Presentation").css({'max-height':'250px', 'overflow':'hidden'});
                    $("#fadeout").show();
                    $("#DivReadMore").show();

                }else{
                $("#Presentation").css({'max-height':'', 'overflow':''});
                    $("#fadeout").hide();
                    $("#DivReadMore").hide();
                }
            }
            </script>
```

Have you an idea ?

Comment: Have you heard of css transitions ? http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition2

Comment: @DarthCoder No, I'm going to look for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in the css of the block: `transition: ease 0.5s all;`.
Possible that it doesn't work, due to the lack of a max-height on the block.

A trick I like doing is just immensely increase the max-height with jQuery.animate. This creates the animation :)

Comment: I've looked for jQuery.animate and I've succeed in doing the animation that I want. I've replaced `$("#Presentation").css({'max-height':'', 'overflow':''});` by `$('#Presentation').animate({ 'max-height':'10000px', 'overflow':'visible' }, {'duration':3000});`

Comment: Awesome :) You can probably do a less huge height, 5000px would still be immense and you can enjoy the animation more ;) upvotes welcome :D

Comment: Indeed it's maybe a little bit too ;)